# Class 'Zend\Log\Logger' not found#0 after upgrade to 2.4.3-p1 version

Tags: magento2.4, magento-upgrade

I've upgraded my **Magento Commerce** version from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3

`composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update`

`composer update`

All seems to work fine but when I try to use *magento/bin* command, I receive this error message:

```
Class 'Zend\Log\Logger' not found#0 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#1 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#2 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#3 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#4 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#5 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#6 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#7 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#8 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#9 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#10 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#11 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#12 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#13 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#14 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#15 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#16 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#17 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#18 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#19 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#20 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#21 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#22 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#23 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#24 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#25 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#26 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#27 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(182): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray()
#28 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#29 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#30 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#31 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#32 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#33 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(153): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#34 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(134): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands()
#35 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1274): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands()
#36 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(629): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init()
#37 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(237): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find()
#38 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#39 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#40 /var/www/passioneunghie2/htdocs/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#41 {main}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it installing **Laminas_Log** module:

`composer require laminas/laminas-log`